# Disable execution of static files as code, with Django, Gunicorn, Nginx

Tags: django, security, nginx, gunicorn, static-files

[Django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/security/#user-uploaded-content-security) state that "If you are serving your own static files, be sure that handlers like Apache’s mod_php, which would execute static files as code, are disabled." How do I disable any such handlers that may exist for Gunicorn + Nginx?

Answer (score 2):

Nginx by default does not have any handlers doing that. If there are no handlers configured in your `server` section in nginx configuration, there is nothing to worry about. If it's clean nginx install, there is nothing to worry about.

Also examine your nginx config if there is only one way to run python code - via gunicorn and django's `wsgi.py` file.

Comment: How would I do such an examination?

Answer (score 1):

Basically the django devs are warning you about a well known web vulnerability.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

As nginx can only serve static files it must use an app server for dynamic pages, a *handler* (php-fpm, gunicorn, uwsgi).

Could be the case that you are using an old nginx's PHP config (with php-fpm as a handler), and you added gunicorn for serving a django app, then a user could manage to upload a PHP file to django's `media` dir and later execute it through your legacy PHP handler.

This is a very odd case, there are no chances this could happen to a fresh site, you never add a PHP handler for a django app.

A PHP handler looks like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  expires off;
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_keep_conn on;
}
```